# Why is there lots of LiteralControls in ASP.NET control tree trace?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, trace

I've made a basic page in ASP.NET WebForms and I was wondering why there are lots of literal controls appearing in the ASP.NET trace. Here a picture.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please post your aspx code - I suspect a lot of the literals are <spans>, <p>, etc that are printed with the webcontrols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All text gets turned into `Literals` by the compilation engine.  When ASP.NET renders the page it take all you markup(`<span>hello</span>`), code(`Control.Add(...)`) and controls(`<asp:button/>`) and builds a control tree.

This is an older article but it explains how the compilation works:

[Compilation and Deployment in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp)

Comment: Yep this is what I was going to say, probably just normal text elements being turned into literals.